# Springboot 2.2 migration gives flyway error: Found more than one migration with version

Tags: java, spring-boot, flyway

Springboot 2.2.0.RELEASE,
Flyway version 6.0.6

I'm trying to migrate to spring boot 2.2. But I get flyway errors When I **start** the application.(mvn clean install works fine) My interpretation is it cant read locations properly, so it thinks files are dublicated. Which are actually, in different folders.

```
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/common,classpath:db/migration/{vendor}
```

ERROR:

> Found more than one migration with version 16.0
>
> Offenders: 
>   ../target/classes/db/migration/h2/V16.0__spring_batch_schema.sql (SQL)
>   ../target/classes/db/migration/oracle/V16.0__spring_batch_schema.sql
>   (SQL)

Comment: How is `{vendor}` replaced at runtime?

Comment: @Smutje How can I check that? cant see in logs

Comment: Well, you pasted your config above, so you should now?!

Comment: @Smutje according to documentation it should be replaced by driver name automatically. apart from that i dont see what actually happens in runtime

Comment: How and where have you mentioned value of {vendor}

Comment: @PramodNikam I did not. that should be extracted from driver name in the url. which worked fine before spring boot migration

Comment: What is the exact Spring Boot 2.2 version you are using? I took a look at the code and I have no idea how you caused this as `{vendor}` is resolved to `DatabaseDriver` enum name.

Comment: Can you try adding spring.datasource.platform=Oracle   property in your configuration

Comment: Is this while running your application or while running a test?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I use 2.2.0.RELEASE

Comment: @M.Deinum When I start the application. mvn clean install works fine

Comment: @PramodNikam thx but didnt help

Comment: I assume {vendor} is not actually replaced by any value and resolved finally to classpath:db/migration/common, so flyway is finding 2 scripts with the same version and this is the cause of the issue, can yout try removing classpath:db/migration/{vendor} from the spring.flyway.locations